# A mapped type may not declare properties or methods.ts(7061)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this mocked data structure:

```
 const dashboard: DashboardData = {
      result: {
        rejected: {
           meta: {
           total_count: randFloat(),
          },
          external_validation_failed: {
            count: randFloat(),
            percentage: randFloat()
          },
          missing_capability: {
            count: randFloat(),
            percentage: randFloat()
          },
          payment_request_cancelled: {
            count: randFloat(),
            percentage: randFloat()
          },
          validation_schema_failed: {
            count: randFloat(),
            percentage: randFloat()
          }
        },
        returned: {
          meta: {
            total_count: randFloat()
          },
          payment_returned: {
            count: randFloat(),
            percentage: randFloat()
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

Where I am trying to define the types as follow:

```
export interface VirtualAccount {
  currency_code: string;
  currency_name: string;
  number: number;
  balance: number;
}

export interface Rejection {
  count: number;
  percentage: number;
}

export interface Returns {
  count: number;
  percentage: number;
}

export type RejectionType =
  | 'external_validation_failed'
  | 'missing_capability'
  | 'payment_request_cancelled'
  | 'validation_schema_failed';

export type ReturnsType = 'payment_returned';

export interface VirtualAccountData {
  virtual_accounts: VirtualAccount[];
}

export interface DashboardData {
  result: {
    rejected: {
      [key in RejectionType]: Rejection;
      meta: {
        total_count: number;
      },
    };
    returned: {
      [key in ReturnsType]: Returns;
      meta: {
        total_count: number;
      },
    };
  };
}
```

The issue is that TS does not like the meta: {total_count: number} in both returned and rejected, saying that a mapped type may not declare properties or methods.ts(7061), prettier just delete that and I am not sure to understand why and how to solve this

Comment: You can use an intersection: `{ [....]: Returns; } & { meta: ... }`

Comment: Please consider paring this code down to a [mre] that demonstrates your issue with a minimum of code.  Something like `type Keys = 'a' | 'b'; type Oops = {[K in Keys]: string; c: number};` should be sufficient (and the solution is to use an intersection as @kelly says, `type Okay = {[K in Keys]: string} & {c: number};`).

Answer (score 2):

What about this one?

```
export interface DashboardData {
  result: {
    rejected: {
      [key in RejectionType]: Rejection;
    } & {
      meta: {
        total_count: number;
      };
    };
    returned: {
      [key in ReturnsType]: Returns;
    } & {
      meta: {
        total_count: number;
      };
    };
  };
}
```

Or you can do

```
export interface DashboardData {
  result: {
    rejected: {
      [key in RejectionType & "meta"]: key extends "meta"
        ? {
            total_count: number;
          }
        : Rejection;
    };
    returned: {
      [key in ReturnsType & "meta"]: key extends "meta"
        ? {
            total_count: number;
          }
        : Returns;
    };
  };
}
```

The reason for this error is  because the types can overlap with each other in such cases.
And the typescript's solution is to only take care of the key declared in a mapped key statement and disregard any other keys surrounding `[key .....]: ...`.